# HTTP 500 when deploying wensite

Tags: c#, iis, deployment, activex

I have used several backend ways to get the logged in Windows user name but alas! I was not successful, then I tried to get it from client-side using ActiveX. It works fine on my localhost but when I deploy it on IIS Server it shows 500 Error. Is there any way to get logged in user name from client-side.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function GetUserName() {

            var net = new ActiveXObject("WScript.NetWork");
            var username = net.UserName;
            alert(username);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="GetUserName()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: which version of iis ?

Comment: @RoxanaSh  
IIS 2012

Comment: Could you please tell me the details error message about 500 error?

Answer (score 0):

That will only work in Internet Explorer, and only if the user allows your site to run ActiveX controls. It also does not mean that Windows Authentication worked on your website.

There is no way to get the username client-side in any other browser.

You are better off getting your Windows Authentication working properly and getting the username on the server. A 500 error indicates and error in your code, not with authentication.